# Running GUI Testing on bamboo agent as service

Tags: continuous-integration, puppeteer, bamboo

There is a way to run CI of GUI testing in bamboo agent as service on windows server?
I don't think it is possible, just run the bamboo agent as a proccess.

I am using puppeteer as libray to run the GUI testing on electron app.

any type of another solution will help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can achieve running the build via PowerShell or cmd prompt, you may do so with a [script task](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/script-289277046.html).

For this, you have to make the agent run as a local user as explained in [this page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/running-bamboo-as-a-windows-service-as-the-local-user-416580754.html). This way, you have the same environment as the local user and the commands to execute your electron app will work successfully.

Comment: I mean not to run the bamboo server itself  only the bamboo agent. The commands are works but the gui testing not. And when I run the agent in foreground its work well.

Comment: The steps to change the agent service's username is the same as described for the server in that page. Did you give it a try already?